# Google Maps React multiple markers from marker.js components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to display multiple markers with Google Maps React just like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/x9mqr94m8z), but my file structure is very different than the example. How can I get it to work with my application?

```js
/* global Google*/

import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Map, GoogleApiWrapper, InfoWindow, Marker } from "google-maps-react";
const mapStyles = {
  width: "45%",
  height: "54%"
};

export class MapContainer extends Component {
  state = {
    showingInfoWindow: false, //Hides or the shows the infoWindow
    activeMarker: {}, //Shows the active marker upon click
    selectedPlace: {} //Shows the infoWindow to the selected place upon a marker
  };

  onMarkerClick = (props, marker, e) =>
    this.setState({
      selectedPlace: props,
      activeMarker: marker,
      showingInfoWindow: true
    });

  render() {
    const google = window.google;
    const data = this.props.data;
    const center = this.props.center;
    return (
      <Map
        google={this.props.google}
        zoom={13}
        style={{}}
        scrollwheel={true}
        initialCenter={{
          lat: 32.71573699,
          lng: -117.16108799
        }}
      >
        <Marker
          onClick={this.onMarkerClick}
          name={""}
          position={{ lat: 32.71573699, lng: -117.16108799 }}
        />
        <InfoWindow
          marker={this.state.activeMarker}
          visible={this.state.showingInfoWindow}
          onClose={this.onClose}
        />
        <Marker
          onClick={this.onMarkerClick}
          name={"John jones Convention Centre"}
          position={{ lat: 32.71673699, lng: -117.16308799 }}
        />

        <InfoWindow
          marker={this.state.activeMarker}
          visible={this.state.showingInfoWindow}
          onClose={this.onClose}
        />
        <Marker
          onClick={this.onMarkerClick}
          name={"John jones Convention Centre"}
          position={
            ({ lat: 32.714587, lng: -117.16919 },
            { lat: 32.714715, lng: -117.157309 })
          }
        />
        <Marker
          onClick={this.onMarkerClick}
          name={"John jones Convention Centre"}
          position={{ lat: 32.716848, lng: -117.159111 }}
        />
      </Map>
    );
  }
}

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: *****
})(MapContainer);
```

Any recommendations how to organize my code to copy the sandbox example? I'm very lost with that part. I know how to do it in normal vanilla JavaScript, but not in React.

Answer (score 0):

You can organize your marker data into an array of objects like so:

```
data: [{onclick: myfunction, name: 'foo',  position: coordinates, id: 'something'}]
```

Then in your render, you can use curly braces to write plain javascript in JSX like so:

```
render() {
  return (
    <Map
      google={this.props.google}
      zoom={13}
      style={{}}
      scrollwheel={true}
      initialCenter={{
        lat: 32.71573699,
        lng: -117.16108799
      }}
    >
      { //curly brace here lets you write javscript in JSX
        data.map(item =>
            <Marker
              key={item.id}
              title={item.name}
              name={item.name}
              position={{ lat: item.lat, lng: item.lng }}
            />
        )
      } //closing brace
     <InfoWindow
       marker={this.state.activeMarker}
       visible={this.state.showingInfoWindow}
       onClose={this.onClose}
     />
    </Map>
  )
}
```

Comment: where do i put that data array ? in my same file i posted above of sample code ? that file is called map.js

Comment: sure, you can put it outside your component as a global constant like: `const DATA = [{...},{...}]` if you have all that data ready.  It really depends on how you're getting your data.

Comment: how im getting my data ? can i just hardcode multiple markers inside that array ? i have multiple coordinates i will like to show on the map ``` var neighborhoods = [
  {lat: 32.712480, lng: -117.167690},
  {lat: 32.702163, lng: -117.151572},
  {lat: 32.716193, lng: -117.167414},
  {lat: 32.712494, lng: -117.164703},
  {lat: 32.709707, lng: -117.169981},
  {lat: 32.714587, lng: -117.169190},
  {lat: 32.714715, lng: -117.157309},
  {lat: 32.716810, lng: -117.157463},
  {lat: 32.722005, lng: -117.158431},
  {lat: 32.716848, lng: -117.159111}
]; ```

Comment: Sure, if you have all the data you can hardcode it into that array.  In the codesandbox link you gave there is an example of a data array it uses.  You'll have to format it like in the codesandbox example.

Comment: i got cannot Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
MapContainer.render for data.map `data.map(item => (`

Comment: that means you named your global constant something else other than data

Comment: i get a blank page on my react app , my console says "Comments inside children section of tag should be placed inside braces  "

Comment: im going to post another question connected to this issue , if you can help i would love that thanks

Comment: how would I be able to display data on the info window